# Assign classes to modals in React Bootstrap

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

I am trying to style the React Bootstrap modal by assigning it classes via the docs here

```
prop: dialogClassName   
type: string
description: A css class to apply to the Modal dialog DOM node.
```

However, it is not showing up as a valid class.

Flexbox, background-color, etc. do not seem to apply to any children of the Modal parent, which makes me think that either Modal disables any styling or I'm doing something incorrectly

Thank you!

```
<ExampleModal 
     dialogClassName="planModal" <--Tried here
     modalState={this.props.modalState}
     openModal={this.props.actions.openModal}
     mealPlanArray={this.props.mealPlanArray}/>
```

render of ExampleModal looks like this

```
render() {                
    if (!this.props.modalState.openDisplay) { return ( <span/>) }
      return (
       <Modal className="TriedHere" show={this.props.modalState.openDisplay} onHide={this.props.openModal}>        
        <Modal.Header>            
          <h2>Bot Activated</h2>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>            
          {this.renderResults()}
        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal>    
    );
  } 
}
```

Can anyone think of a way to style the contents of React Modal?

Comment: Put the `dialogClassName` prop on `<Modal ..`?

Comment: As azium says, it's a prop for the `<Modal />` component, if you are looking to pass it in from the parent component, then in this case you would have:  `<Modal dialogClassName={this.props.dialogClassName} ... />`

Answer (score 4):

Just to elaborate on the comments a bit,

In your current implementation you are setting `dialogClassName` on the component responsible for rendering the `<Modal />` component, rather than, [as the docs say](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#modals-props), on the `<Modal />` component itself.

This means that you have access to `this.props.dialogClassName` inside `<ExampleModal />` rather than `<Modal />` which is where react-bootstrap expects it.

There's nothing wrong with passing down the className from a higher level component, in fact it's a pretty likely use case that you would want to be conditionally rendering some styles to your `<Modal />` component. Just be sure that it gets the prop `dialogClassName`.

In your case you just need to pass it one more level down:

```
<ExampleModal 
 dialogClassName="planModal"  <-- This is a custom prop that you have created, 
 ...                              it's been given the same name, but the name 
 ...                              could be anything really.
 ... 
/>
```

Then inside of the render method of `<ExampleModal />`:

```
<Modal 
  dialogClassName={this.props.dialogClassName}  <-- This is the prop that react-boostrap expects 
  show={this.props.modalState.openDisplay} 
  onHide={this.props.openModal}>
```

On a side note: the code samples in the react-bootstrap docs are actually editable in-browser. Which can definitely be pretty useful whenever you're looking to test out things like the optional props for the different components they offer.

Comment: Hey Brad! Thanks for answering. I tried placing the prop there as well (under the ModalComponent, but I still couldn't get any style to apply. Any idea why this would be?

Comment: Have you double checked that it's adding the class to the `modal-dialog` div in devTools? It definitely should be, maybe an issue with the actual styles?